# Profiler overhead Vs Logging overhead to run Dex for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, dex

I am running Dex in test environment. Dex uses either system.profile or logs from Mongo's log.
I have to start Dex with any of these two options. But both profiler and logging(enabled) comes with performance cost. Which thing I should prefer to get into Dex. What costs more profiler/logging?

Comment: Why don't you try both and compare?

Comment: I have tried with profiler.. the whole process is time consuming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profiler requires writing to the database you are profiling, and so can impact performance if you are hitting lock contention.  Basically, at the moment, the locks in MongoDB are per-database and so adding a collection (which the profiler does) and hence increasing the overall writes to the database will add to the amount of write locking you are doing on that database.  If you are not hitting lock contention, then it's not a big deal but it's worth being aware of the potential for side effects.

Logging writes out slow operations to a file, and does not add to lock contention, so I would start there as a general preference and only move to the profiler if you have a specific need.   Don't forget that you can adjust what constitutes a [slow operation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/) if needed, and it will be honored by the profiler and the logs.

Comment: I'm bit confused with this line => "Logging writes out slow operations to a file", so please correct me, does that means Logging writes all operations to log file but profiler write only slow operation.

Comment: Logging writes out a lot of information, including operations that breach the slow threshold by default.  The profiler is off by default and so does nothing unless you turn it on.  If you turn it on, the profiling level determines what is written - at level 1 it writes slow operations to the profile collection (similar to the logs) and at level 2 it writes all operations to the profile collection.